# I trained a model using Logistic Regression, but when I deployed it using streamlit and then test the data it gives an error

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

This is the error when I test the model for user input

```
ValueError: dtype='numeric' is not compatible with arrays of bytes/strings.
Convert your data to numeric values explicitly instead.
```

This was my whole code for the modelling part

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

breast_cancer_dataset = sklearn.datasets.load_breast_cancer()

d_frame = pd.DataFrame(breast_cancer_dataset.data, columns = breast_cancer_dataset.feature_names)
d_frame['label'] = breast_cancer_dataset.target
d_frame.isnull().sum()
d_frame.describe()
d_frame['label'].value_counts()
d_frame.groupby('label').mean()

X = d_frame.drop(columns = 'label', axis = 1)
Y = d_frame['label']

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 2)

model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)

X_train_prediction = model.predict(X_train)
training_data_acc = accuracy_score(Y_train, X_train_prediction)

X_test_prediction = model.predict(X_test)
testing_data_acc = accuracy_score(Y_test, X_test_prediction)

ip_data = (13.54,14.36,87.46,566.3,0.09779,0.08129,0.06664,0.04781,0.1885,0.05766,0.2699,0.7886,2.058,23.56,0.008462,0.0146,0.02387,0.01315,0.0198,0.0023,15.11,19.26,99.7,711.2,0.144,0.1773,0.239,0.1288,0.2977,0.07259)
ip_as_numpy_arr = np.asarray(ip_data)
ip_data_reshaped = ip_as_numpy_arr.reshape(1,-1)

prediction = model.predict(ip_data_reshaped)
if(prediction[0] == 0):
    print("The Breast Cancer is Malignant")
else:
    print("The Breast Cancer is Benign")

import pickle

filename = 'trained_model.sav'
pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))

loaded_model = pickle.load(open('trained_model.sav', 'rb'))

ip_data = (13.54,14.36,87.46,566.3,0.09779,0.08129,0.06664,0.04781,0.1885,0.05766,0.2699,0.7886,2.058,23.56,0.008462,0.0146,0.02387,0.01315,0.0198,0.0023,15.11,19.26,99.7,711.2,0.144,0.1773,0.239,0.1288,0.2977,0.07259)
ip_as_numpy_arr = np.asarray(ip_data)
ip_data_reshaped = ip_as_numpy_arr.reshape(1,-1)

prediction = loaded_model.predict(ip_data_reshaped)
if(prediction[0] == 0):
    print("The Breast Cancer is Malignant")
else:
    print("The Breast Cancer is Benign")
```

Comment: Where exactly? Please update your post with the **full** error trace (and remove any code that may come *after* the error) - see how to create a [mre].

Comment: Please ensure you add the relevant streamlit code as well

Answer (score 0):

1. First check the data types of all the columns if **any string/ or non-numeric data** is present in the column with the help of the **dtype** method, if any values are found convert them into the numeric format with the help of encoding techniques.
2. Recheck the **feature engineering** step specially **reshaping the data** at the time of saving the model or loading the model.